# Laravel 5 get attribute from collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `$location` collection that looks like this:

```
Collection {#225 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => GoogleAddress {#336 ▼
      -id: "ChIJjWwHAP72w0cR44_HJ-bRcJE"
      -locationType: "ROOFTOP"
      -resultType: array:1 [▶]
      -formattedAddress: ""
      -streetAddress: null
      -intersection: null
      -political: ""
      -colloquialArea: null
      -ward: null
      -neighborhood: null
      -premise: null
      -subpremise: null
      -naturalFeature: null
      -airport: null
      -park: null
      -pointOfInterest: null
      -establishment: null
      -subLocalityLevels: AdminLevelCollection {#339 ▶}
      -coordinates: Coordinates {#331 ▶}
      -bounds: Bounds {#332 ▶}
      -streetNumber: "21"
      -streetName: ""
      -subLocality: null
      -locality: ""
      -postalCode: ""
      -adminLevels: AdminLevelCollection {#337 ▶}
      -country: Country {#335 ▶}
      -timezone: null
      -providedBy: "google_maps"
    }
    1 => GoogleAddress {#344 ▶}
    2 => GoogleAddress {#352 ▶}
    3 => GoogleAddress {#360 ▶}
    4 => GoogleAddress {#368 ▶}
  ]
}
```

So I am trying to get the formattedAddress like this:

```
$location[0]->formattedAddress
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot access private property
>   Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMaps\Model\GoogleAddress::$formattedAddress

Anyone can help me out here?

Comment: That doesn't work either I get: `Cannot use object of type`

Comment: if you need only first record change query and use -> first()

Answer (score 2):

It's a collection Do it like this

```
$location->first()->formattedAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is private, meaning you can only access it from within the same class. In this case, the class has a getter method called `getFormattedAddress()` you can use.

Source: https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/master/src/Provider/GoogleMaps/Model/GoogleAddress.php#L182

Solution: `$location->first()->getFormattedAddress()`

And a bit of advice, if you don't understand the private part, you really should have a look at the PHP documentation on visibility: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score -2):

First, try to get the first object with $model->first()

If not, try to use mutators:(Here an example)

```
public function getNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['firstName'];
}
```